# JQueryMobile and Credit Card Entry

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

Does JQueryMobile have good support for entering credit card information.  Users have a really difficult time entering 16 digits and followed by expiration dates etc.  I would like to see a good JQueryMobile view example of how to enter credit card/reward card details.  Any suggestions for keeping the Android keyboard properly positioned during this process as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to follow the demo examples:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/forms-all.html

Input for the 16 digit, Security Code on the back ( sometimes front ) of the card

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/textinputs/
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp ( Max Length )
- http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp ( optional Placeholder )

Example ( Note: The characters in a password field are masked [shown as asterisks or circles] ):

```
<input type="password" name="credit_card_number" id="credit_card_number" value="" placeholder="1234567890123456">
<input type="password" name="security_code" id="security_code" value="" placeholder="123">
```

You could use a mask feature if you don't like the password option, not sure if there are any plugins to 'mask previous input character onblur mask all' but that would make for a nice one

- [JQuery apply input mask to field onfocus and remove onblur so to avoid problems with placeholder text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816511/jquery-apply-input-mask-to-field-onfocus-and-remove-onblur-so-to-avoid-problems)

DateBox for the Expiration Date

- http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

Maybe add some Credit Card validation as well?

- http://paweldecowski.github.com/jQuery-CreditCardValidator/
- http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/creditcard

Comment: Did you mean to say that a `type="password"` form input is good for the 3 digit security code? Which BTW is sometimes located on the front of the card :) Good answer though. There isn't really a all-in-one solution but using these attributes/controls is going to help.

Comment: @Jasper yeah using input type password would mask the numbers for security, updated my answer with an example

Comment: I've got a beef with that :) I hate when you're 10 digits into a number and then the password input takes over and hides your last digit, and all you can do is start-over... Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Jasper I do like how iOS masks the previous characters and on blur mask all but haven't found or made a plugin for that yet

Comment: This is a great question - i'd be very interested in any sort of good ideas of what credit card entry *should* be like on mobile - that would make a lovely plugin.  And I totally agree with @Jasper - password masking the CC# is incredibly frustrating sometimes.